# YAML Release into Environment, Post deployment condition

Tags: azure-devops

In Classic UI Release pipelines, you can specifiy pre-stage and post-stage Gates.
However using YAML releases, and projects Environments, you can only use the `Approval & Checks` feature on the Environment.

AFAIK this only behaves as an pre-deployment gate. Is there a way to perform a post-deployment check using YAML releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's not available right now. But there is a related feature request in our user voice site:

> **Add pre and post-deployment approvals for multi-stage pipelines (YAML), similar to release definitions**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/567845/add-pre-and-post-deployment-approvals-for-multi-st.html

Kindly vote up and track the status on it. Our PM will also review it.